# perl: multithread write and tail file

Tags: multithreading, perl

I'm working on a simple use-case of perl multi-thread: one thread writes to a file and another thread tails the file. here is the code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use threads;
use File::Tail;

my $file = 'data.txt';
sub tail_file{
    my $file=File::Tail->new($file);
    while (defined(my $line=$file->read)) {
        print "$line";
    }
}

sub write_file{
    open (MYFILE, ">> $file");
    print MYFILE scalar localtime .  "  A data.\n";
    close (MYFILE); 
    print 'write done!';
}

my $t_tail = threads->new(\&tail_file);
$t_tail->join();

my $t_write = threads->new(\&write_file);
$t_write->join();
```

When running, this program is stuck on the console.

Answer (score 3):

If you get rid of the call to `$t_tail->join()`, your program actually works fine.  You need to get rid of this call because your `$t_tail` thread will run forever (and thus will never `join`), and your `$t_write` thread will never get kicked off.

You should know, however, that even if you get rid of that line, if the `$t_write` thread executes before the `$t_tail` thread (since the order of execution with threads is never guaranteed), then it may be the case you finish writing to the file before your `File::Tail` object is even initialized.  And since `File::Tail` only captures changes to the file that happen *after* it is initialized, it may look like nothing is happening at all.

Lastly, you may think that `File::Tail` works similarly to the Linux/Unix `tail`, but the [documentation](http://search.cpan.org/~mgrabnar/File-Tail-0.99.3/Tail.pm) shows that the default wait times used by the module are quite generous in comparison to the Linux/Unix counterpart:

> **maxinterval**
>
> The maximum number of seconds (real number) that will be spent
>   sleeping. Default is 60, meaning File::Tail will never spend more than
>   sixty seconds without checking the file.
>
> **interval**
>
> The initial number of seconds (real number) that will be spent
>   sleeping, before the file is first checked. Default is ten seconds,
>   meaning File::Tail will sleep for 10 seconds and then determine, how
>   many new lines have appeared in the file.

If you run your program, and your `File::Tail` object does happen to get initialized before you start writing to the file, then you may have to wait a while (10 seconds) before you see anything on your console.

Comment: Didn't find in the document how to change the interval(i.e., the initial number of seconds). Is there any chance we can do the change? BTW, it's right that it takes File:Tail very long to get initialized to tail. I've been wondering why ... :-)

Comment: From the documentation, it looks like you can pass custom values for those (and other) parameters when calling `new()`.  For example: `$file=File::Tail->new(name=>$name, maxinterval=>300);` ... hope that helps! :)